# viewForHeaderInSection - create header that would display properly in all cases

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios

I have an interesting problem/question and i'm not sure if it is even doable. So I have a custom header view for regular UITableView. But it's transparent and it doesn't fill fill table width. So it displayed properly when table is scrolled and this header view is displayed above cell content (sticked to the top). But when same header is displayed between two sections down - it looks ugly, because it's transparent and it's either displayed above black rectangle or above table background.

I was wondering is there way to customize header view for when it's stick to the top and when it's not. Or... may be it's possible to specify what needs to be displayed underneath header view when it's between sections. Something like sectionSeparatorView?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: added a screenshot. is it clear where the problem is?

Comment: What should it look like? Seems to be what I'd expect. Cool idea BTW.

Comment: @Eiko: Ideally I want to display white background under SECOND header. And leave FIRST header same (transparent).

Comment: Why not simply fix the main background image to have white in the region of the table cells?

Comment: That actually I think might work. I will have to try it tonight. Thank you.

Comment: Actually that worked pretty well. Thank you Eiko. Do you want to post it as an answer so I can reward you with the bounty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the best solution for my problem was to define some kind of background for the UITableViewController. It was provided in comments to the original post, and unfortunately author didn't put it as separate answer so I could not award bounty to him.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. Was a quick solution anyway. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not to change to UITableViewStyleGrouped ?
In that case section headers doesn't float atop of table cells.

Comment: I want them float. It's fine behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

To set the header height to 1px, and then make the first cell of each section larger to create some whitespace for under your header.

Comment: Removing headers and using first cell is not something that I want to do. I DO want header to stuck at the top. I just need a way to change background under SECOND header.

Comment: I don't mean remove the header. I mean, use the header but at 1px height. It will then overflow over the next cell, which you make larger so it has a white background.

Comment: Or why don't you modify the table background to match what you want? just add a subview to the top and bottom with the original background?

Comment: If I make header 1px it won't float properly. 1px header will float, but the first cell which will have all header information will not. I will see if my goal can be achieved by playing with table background...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you wanna do is not possible. 
I tought of two ways to workaround this problem.
First, delete the header and use the first cell of each section as a header with a different cell style, so it will never stay at the top like a header.
The other way is to change the layout of the header, instead of being transparent, with a background with the same color of the background of the view.

Comment: First one won't work. See other comments. Second one will, but then TOP FIRST header will not look good. You will not see cell under it...